# How to compare and parse a yaml from file in s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml

I have two files that come in from a scheduled event using `aws-lambda`. I then have another lambda that gets triggered from each of the files that gets dropped. When the files get dropped I need the lambda to look at my `config.yaml` compare it to a file that dropped into into my `s3`bucket. However, I can't seem to flatten out the yaml and compare the file name to the name in the yaml.

For example:
s3-bucket name: `qa_data_cleaning_bucket/incoming`
filename = `identity_check.csv` #or any of the files

`config.yaml`

```
#one file's configurations
    identity_check:
        identity_check_events: &identity_check_events_metadata
        application_name: id_verification
        schema_name: ingested_id_verfication
        file_type: CSV_WITH_HEADER
        custom_delimiter: 124
#another file's configurations
    snd_file:
        snd_file_events: &nd_file_events_metadata
        application_name: name_snd_file
        schema_name: ingested_snd_file
        file_type: CSV_WITH_HEADER
        custom_delimiter: 124
```

sudo code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  record = event["Records"][0]
  event_source = record["eventSource"]
  file_key = record["s3"]["object"].split('/')[-1]
  
  with open('config.yaml', 'r') as config_search:
    config_data = yaml.safe_load(config_search)
    if file_name[-4] == yaml_key
    pull out the rest of the metadata details.
```

Since the name of my file is `identity_check` I need it to look at my metadata and pull out the rest of the details so that I can start a process to ingest the data to its particular endpoint.

I need to pull out the file name without its extensions. From there, find that particular section in the YAML file, retrieve the schema name and its contents.

In this particular example, I have an identity_check.csv file that needs to be mapped to the identity_check schema in the yaml. And when the next file drops in that folder, I need the that one to be mapped to that schema. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You have not shown your complete code, so it is difficult to offer advice. For example, what is `file_name` and what is `yaml_key`? Can you clarify exactly what you are wanting to do in your code? For example, is this your requirement: _Get the filename without extension (eg `identity_check` if the filename is `identity_check.csv`) and find that section in the YAML file, then retrieve the `schema_name`._

Comment: yeah, sorry for the confusion, that is exactly what I'm looking for. Get the file_name without the extension. There will be multiple files that drop in that folder. From there, find that particular section in the YAML file, retrieve the schema name and it's contents